# Sorting list of objects alphabetically based on another list JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

i want to sort a list of objects alphabetically based on another list of characters and the property 'name'

this is the sorting list and the order that i wish to follow in order to sort my list:

```
 const SortingArray = [['a','á','à','â','ä','å','ã'],['b'],['c','ç'],['d'],
                      ['e','é','è','ê','ë'],['f'],['g'],['h'],['i','í','ì','î','ï'],
                      ['j'],['k'],['l'],['m'],['n','ñ'],['o','ó','ò','ô','ö','õ'],['p'],
                      ['q'],['r'],['s','š'],['t'],['u','ú','ù','û','ü'],
                      ['v'],['w'],['x'],['y','ý','ÿ'],['z','ž']];
```

and this is the list that i want to sort :

```
var listToSort = [{name: 'Étape',code: 'c12'},{name: 'Abc',code: 'c14'},{name: 'Ûrter',code: 'c15'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by implementing a sort function that calculates the index of the first character of the words in the SortingArray like this:

```
    listToSort.sort((a, b) => {
        const aIndex = SortingArray.findIndex(charArray => 
            charArray.includes(a.name[0].toLowerCase())
        );
        const bIndex = SortingArray.findIndex(charArray => 
            charArray.includes(b.name[0].toLowerCase())
        );
        return aIndex - bIndex;
    });
```